# SHA512Managed hashSize

Tags: c#, hash, sha512

the official documentation of MSDN says

**The hash size for the SHA512Managed algorithm is 512 bits.**

When I run the following code

```
        byte[] dataToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello Worlds");
        SHA512Managed sha = new SHA512Managed(); 
        byte[] hashedData = sha.ComputeHash(dataToEncode);
        string hashedDataString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedData);
```

my HasheDataString is only 64 long (hashedDataString.Length) and hasheData is only 64 long (hashedData.Length).  What exactly is this **512?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each byte has eight bits, so 64 bytes is 64 * 8 = 512 bits.

The base64 encoded string of the 64 bytes is 88 characters long. The base64 encoding stores six bit in each character, so 512 bits needs 512 / 6 ~ 85.3 characters, plus two extra characters to get to an even four-character boundary.

Answer (score 3):

512bits means the size in binary, ones and zeroes. When you convert this to a string, all ones and zeroes become characters, each character consists of 8bits. So then you have 512bits divided 8bits per character makes 64 characters in a string.

Comment: No, a characters is 16 bits. It's the bytes that are eigth bits.

Comment: It is a [base64 string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), in which each character consists of 8 bits.

Comment: In a base64 string each character holds 6 bits of data (64 different values), not 8 bits.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

user3547774 question has a typo, HasheDataString is 88 characters long.

Guffa has the good response.

About c# string :
[Each character in a string is defined by a Unicode scalar value ... encoded by using UTF-16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.aspx#Characters)

So Base64 encoding only use 6 bits over 16 per character to encode the data.